# Can a c++ class include itself as an member?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to speed up a python routine by writing it in C++, then using it using ctypes or cython.

I'm brand new to c++. I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ Express as it's free.

I plan to implement an expression tree, and a method to evaluate it in postfix order.

The problem I run into right away is:

```
class Node {
    char *cargo;
    Node left;
    Node right;
};
```

I can't declare `left` or `right` as `Node` types.

Comment: "_I can't declare left or right as Node types._" This should include an explanation of why, with verbatim quotes of any errors received. Presumably your compiler complained about something like `Node` being an incomplete type at that point in time.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

No, because the object would be infinitely large (because every `Node` has as members two other `Node` objects, which each have as members two other `Node` objects, which each... well, you get the point).

You can, however, have a pointer to the class type as a member variable:

```
class Node {
    char *cargo;
    Node* left;   // I'm not a Node; I'm just a pointer to a Node
    Node* right;  // Same here
};
```

Comment: In this case a bare pointer is the proper and intuitive choice. It is worth mentioning that holding myself as a member can be using other choices, such as: `reference`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr`, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63365537/c-instance-of-same-class/63365597#63365597

Answer (score 58):

Just for completeness, note that a class can contain a static instance of itself:

```
class A
{
    static A a;
};
```

This is because static members are not actually stored in the class instances, so there is no recursion.

Comment: This has turned my head upside down for a bit, so I would add something: in this case, each instance of the class 'A' will only store a pointer to a space allocated in static memory for the particular 'a' instance. So the 'a' instance also have a pointer, pointing to itself infinitely: `A* someA = new A;` `someA->.a.a.a...etc.` (supposing 'a' is a public attribut) and that is why memory used in finite.

Comment: @hymced: No, none of the instances of `A` contains a pointer, certainly nothing pointing to the static member. `->` and `.` will get you that object thanks to name lookup rules, not because of any memory layout.

Comment: @Lightness-Races-in-Orbit you are right, there are no pointers in the above example. What I meant is that the used memory is finite, not because the static member is stored outside of the class instance, but rather because this particular static member is the same for any class instance. It is also because the ´a´ instance only contains itself and nothing else. Add a simple (non-static) int member in the mix, you are out of memory, even with a static class member.

Comment: @hymced That is simply not true. Why do you think adding a non-`static` `int` member to `A` would cause the computer to run out of memory?

Comment: Again, I was wrong : 'A' would have an int member (not in static memory) different from 'a' (in static memory), but the int member of 'a' would be the same than 'a.a' (since 'a.a' IS 'a'), same than 'a.a.a', etc. So used memory is finite.

Comment: @hymced With static members the class is simply used as a namespace. The connection of the static member to the class is purely syntactical (including potential access restrictions). To the linker etc. it is like any global variable and can be used thus (pass it to C functions etc.)

Comment: This should have been the right accepted answer. The static keyword seems clever.

Answer (score 13):

No, but it can have a reference or a pointer to itself:

```
class Node
{
    Node *pnode;
    Node &rnode;
};
```

Comment: References don't really work in this case because they aren't allowed to be null, and you need null endings or the graph would be infinite.

Comment: You could create a dummy node to take the pace of NULL. However, this doesn't work well because references can't be reassigned to something else, and modification to any link would require reconstructing all nodes up to the root.

Comment: @Blindy: You could also set the node reference to `*this` instead of NULL.

Comment: @Blindy, @All: Yes. Like I say, I'm a  real beginner. I've been having a very difficult time trying to put this together.

Comment: @Blindy but there is `std::optional< std::reference_wrapper<Node> >`! Don't laugh. It's easier to throw if 'null' and less prone to accidental pointer arithmetic and suchlike.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pointer, *& better initialized*:

```
class Node {
    char * cargo = nullptr;
    Node * left = nullptr;
    Node * right = nullptr;
};
```

**Modern C++**

It is a better practice to use **smart-pointers** (unique_ptr, shared_ptr, etc.), instead of memory allocations by 'new':

```
#include <string>
#include <memory> // For 'std::unique_ptr' 

class Node {
public:
    std::string cargo;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
};

int main()
{
    auto bt = std::make_unique<Node>();

    (*bt).cargo = "Coffee";
    (*bt).left = std::make_unique<Node>();
}
```

Comment: How did this add any value to the already existing answers?