# Having attributes of the same class in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, data-structures

I want to implement a generic, tree structure with C++ - with classes! - and this tree is composed by a key (which in my case is an integer) and a leftChild and rightChild attributes, which should be both of the same type as the tree itself

In C I can do this like:

```
typedef struct avl {
    int key;
    int bf;
    struct avl *leftChild;
    struct avl *rightChild;
} AVLTree;
```

And I attempted the following in my C++ code:

```
class MTree {
    public:
        int key;
        int bf;

        MTree leftChild;
        MTree rightChild;

        MTree() {}
        ~MTree() {};
 }
```

But it won't work and it gives me the following error message:

`mtree-ops.cpp:12: error: field ‘leftChild’ has incomplete type`

`mtree-ops.cpp:13: error:error: field ‘rightChild’ has incomplete type`

So you see, looks like I can't say my class has an attribute of its own type because that's like trying to make reference to something that doesn't really exist at the time of the definition. How can this be done using C++ classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I cannot post comments yet.)

In short, `MTree leftChild` would have two `MTree` children of its own, each of which would have two children, and so on.  Thus, `MTree` objects would be infinitely big, since they would contain infinitely many `MTree` instances.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706129/can-a-c-class-include-itself-as-an-attribute) which is essentially identical.  As mentioned there, you must resort to references or pointers to children, giving individual `MTree` objects finite size.  For example,

```
class MTree
{
[...]
public:
    MTree* leftChild;
    MTree* rightChild;
};
```

(You could replace `MTree*` with `MTree&`.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idomatic C++11 way to do it:

```
#include <memory>
class MTree {
  public:
    int key;
    int bf;

    std::unique_ptr<MTree> leftChild;
    std::unique_ptr<MTree> rightChild;

    MTree():key(0), bf(0) {}
    ~MTree() {};
};
```

`std::unique_ptr` is a smart pointer with next to zero overhead that represents a pointer that the containing `struct` has ownership over, and which can be `nullptr`.

To add a child, simply `leftChild.reset( new MTree );`

When a parent is destroyed, all of its children are destroyed automatically.  If you want to take a child from a parent, do `std::unique_ptr<MTree> branch = std::move( parent.leftChild );`, which claims ownership over the left child and removes it from the parent.

If you just want a non-owning pointer, use `parent.leftChild.get()`.  If you want to access the left child's `key`, `parent.leftChild->key` will do it (note: you are responsible for checking for `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should look like this

```
class MTree {
    public:
        int key;
        int bf;

        MTree * leftChild;
        MTree * rightChild;

        MTree() {}
        ~MTree() {};
}
```