# map of derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, dictionary, polymorphism

I have a base class

```
class Person{
public:
    Person(string name , int age ){
        this -> name = name;
        this -> age  = age;
    }
    virtual void getInfo(){
        cout << "Person " << name << " " << age;
    }
   void add(string name , const Person & b){
        a[name] = b
   }
protected:
    string name;
    int age;
    map<string , Person > a;
};
```

That contains map of object type Person. I want to push various derived classes into that map e.g

Derived class

```
class Kid : public Person{
public:
    Kid(string name, int age):Person(name,age){};
    virtual void getInfo( ){
        cout << "Kid " << name << " " << age;
    }
};
```

I want `add` method of Person class to bahave such as

```
Person one("John",25);
one.add("Suzie",15);
```

Which fails. I know i can remake the code using pointers e.g

```
map<string , Person*> a   
void add( string name , Person *b){
      a[name] = b;
}
Person one("John",25);
one.add(new Kid("Suzie",15))
```

But is there a way how to achieve it without using pointers?

Comment: No, because of [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). You need to use smart pointer at least.

Comment: If you hold on place of `Person` object with `Kid` class, you get crash of your program, is it really what you want?

Comment: I'd recommend using `map<string ,std::unique_ptr<Person>>`.

Comment: could you elaborate about using unique_ptr?

Comment: @trolkura It's handy to hide all of the nasty memory management things: [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: im quite new to this , i tried declaring map with unique_ptr , and tried pushing in an  pointer / non pointer and still the same.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't obtain polymorphism without using references or pointers.

The issue is easily understood by thinking that a non pointer object requires to store the whole class data (including the vtable).

This means that a `map<string, person>` will store somewhere `person` instances in a `sizeof(person)` slot.

But a `sizeof(person)` can't contain enough data to store additional information of subclasses of `person`. This leads to [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Answer (score 0):

your original design ends up recursing infinitely. You need a polymorphic map, but do you need it to be a member of the class??

Take a look at this question [Can a c++ class include itself as an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706129/can-a-c-class-include-itself-as-an-attribute)