# Incomplete Type Is Not Allowed

Tags: c++

Attempting to create as simple parent/child node class but running into Incomplete Type Is Not Allowed error. Why?

```
class Node {
public:
    Node ParentNode;  //Error on this line
    string NodeName;


    Node(Node *node) : ParentNode(*node) {

    }
};
```

Comment: If it was allowed then you got an infinite compilation. The compiler will try recursively to insert the definition of Node for each its instance.:)

Comment: You can make it a pointer.

Comment: `Node ParentNode;` => `Node *ParentNode;` ?

Comment: What's the size of a `Node`? Ignoring padding, it's the size of a `Node` + the size of a `string`. See how that doesn't really make sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a c++ class include itself as an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706129/can-a-c-class-include-itself-as-an-attribute)

Answer (score 6):

You are trying:

```
Node ParentNode;  //Error on this line
```

but Node is not a complete type at this point (you are in fact defining it at this point), a structure cannot contain an instance of itself, it can contain a pointer or reference to an instance of itself but not an actual instance. After all, if such recursive containment were allowed, where would it end?

Answer (score 3):

The error hints at the fact that the definition of a class is incomplete while the class is being defined.

An object can't contain an instance of its own type – it would be infinitely large.

You want

```
Node* ParentNode;
```

and

```
Node(Node *node) : ParentNode(node)
```