# Recursive Class Definition yields to invalid pointers in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to create a class that has a recursive structure, like a Matrioska doll, to be clearer.
Like this
A class contains 8 children of type A.
I'm using pointers as pointed out in this question:
[Can a c++ class include itself as an member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706129/can-a-c-class-include-itself-as-an-member)

And I'm assigning an Index value at each class instance, to keep track of how down the class is with respect to the parent one.

This is My code:

> Tester.h

```
#pragma once

const unsigned int MAX_RECURSION = 3;

struct Tester
{

    Tester* Children[2][2][2];
    unsigned int Index;

    Tester(unsigned int index) : Index(index), Children()
    {
        std::cout << std::string(index, '-') << "(" << index << ")" << std::endl;
        if (index < MAX_RECURSION) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++) {

                        this->Children[x][y][z] = &Tester(index + 1);;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    void Walk(int& tr)
    {

        if (this->Index < MAX_RECURSION) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
                        tr++;
                        (this->Children[x][y][z])->Walk(tr);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

};
```

> Main.cpp:

```
#include "Tester.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {

    int c = 0;

    Tester t(1);
    t.Walk(c);

    return 0;
}
```

The value c holds the number of times the function `Tester::Walk` run.

By running this code, all of the classes get correctly created, as you can be seen in the output log:

```
-(1)
--(2)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
--(2)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
--(2)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
--(2)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
--(2)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
--(2)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
--(2)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
--(2)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
---(3)
```

A class with index 3 was indeed created 8*8 times so 64. (8 for each recursion).

But when I try to `Walk` down the `Children` variable of the `t`, the walk function only gets run 8 times. By debugging I later found out that only the first 8 Tester classes (the first inside the t clas in main.cpp) have the right index, as the other ones have an index of `3435973836`. I initially thought that the recursive creation had problems, but the log shows that the indexes work correctly (the one gets printed 1 time, the 2 8 times and the 3 64 times).

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: @user4581301 how may I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thou shalt not store pointers to temporary objects.

Their [Lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) is too short. The compiler may be warning you of this, if not preventing it outright with a compiler error. Eg. g++9.3 emits

```
..\src\test.cpp:18:68: error: taking address of rvalue [-fpermissive]
   18 |                         this->Children[x][y][z] = &Tester(index + 1);;
      |                                                                    ^
```

In

```
this->Children[x][y][z] = &Tester(index + 1);;
```

`Tester(index + 1)` creates a an unnamed, temporary object that only lives until the end of the line. Before you'll get a chance to use a pointer to this object, it has gone out of scope and been destroyed.

The most direct solution to this problem is to manually dynamically allocate

```
this->Children[x][y][z] = new Tester(index + 1);
```

but you must now manually manage the lifetime of all of the allocated `Tester`s, and this can be a lot trickier than it appears.

The recommended solution would be to use a smart pointer to manage the lifetime of the `Tester`s. I will use [a `std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) because it is the simplest and most restrictive smart pointer:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // unique_ptr, make_unique
const unsigned int MAX_RECURSION = 3;

struct Tester
{

    std::unique_ptr<Tester> Children[2][2][2]; 
        // array of Testers with scope-managed lifetime. When the array goes out of 
        // scope, all of the Testers will be automatically destroyed.
    unsigned int Index;

    Tester(unsigned int index) :  Children(), Index(index)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(index, '-') << "(" << index << ")" << std::endl;
        if (index < MAX_RECURSION) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++) {

                        this->Children[x][y][z] = std::make_unique<Tester>(index + 1);
                            // makes a unique_ptr referencing a brand-new Tester
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    void Walk(int& tr)
    {

        if (this->Index < MAX_RECURSION) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
                        tr++;
                        (this->Children[x][y][z])->Walk(tr);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```