# How can I declare an attribute with the same class of it?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'd like to build a Fraction class and to do that I want to use the class to declare the attributes inside of it like this.

```
class Function {
     private:
          Fraction num;
          Fraction den;
     public:
         // Methods...
}
```

How can I do it? Thank you in advance for your time.

P.S.: sorry for my bad english and also for my bad programming, I'm new to OOP :D.

Comment: You cannot declare a class that has a member variable of that self-same class in the class (because of infinite recursion, the class would be infinitely big).  You can declare a class that has a member variable pointer of that self-same class in the class.

Comment: No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706129/can-a-c-class-include-itself-as-an-member

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It seems like you already have (almost) working code. Maybe you should take our [tour] and see [ask], then provide a [mre] and ask a more specific question. What's wrong with the piece of code you've shown?

Comment: @churill, I am pretty sure that code does not work.

Comment: The numerator and denominator of a fraction are integers, not fractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use class itself as member.

but you can do something like that with pointers:

```
class A
{
public:
  A* first;
  A* something_else;
}
```

most data structure like linked list or list or tree used this approach.